# ABNewPersonViewController | address field input

Tags: ios, xcode

I am looking for a `UIControl` just like `ABNewPersonViewController`'s address field input. I am building an app that will ask user for its mailing address. Mailing addresses have different components around the globe e.g. a US address will have a state and a zip code in it, whereas a PK address will contain province and postal code in it.

apple's `ABNewPersonViewController` changes its address field inputs according to the country selected. I am looking to integrate this functionality in my app. I have already tried looking for `ABNewPersonViewController`'s customization but it is not customizable. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Apple's internationalization guide? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html

This guide should cover what you need. App localization is well worth the effort.

Addresses can also be detected using NSDataDetecor  (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009936) if you need the flexibility you can use this class to check if a string is an address.